# how to calculate Percentage from Dynamic Pivot Query in Sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

**i want to show every subject's marks in front of students and also percentage of total subjects.**

For this Purpose i make dynamic pivot query this query gives me all subjects 
but not percentage actually i do not know how to calculate percentage because my columns are dynamic

```
    Declare @cols AS nvarchar(max),
    @query as nvarchar(max)

Select @cols = Stuff(
    (   
     Select distinct ','+ QUOTENAME(SubNameUr) 
     from TblSubject Sub
     Inner join TblSubClassRel subr on Sub.SubId = subr.SubId
     inner join TblClass C on subr.ClassID = C.ClassID
     inner join  TblClassSchedule csh on subr.ClassID = csh.ClassID
     inner join TblSubAss sba on subr.ClassSubRelId = sba.ClassSubRelId
     inner join TblSemAssigning SemA on csh.SemAssId = SemA.SemAssId
     inner join TblAcademicYear Ay on SemA.AcademicYearId = Ay.AcademicYearId 
     Where csh.ClassSchID = 207 and Ay.AcademicYearName ='2008-09'
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

Set @query = ' Select pivot1.FullName,pivot1.ClassName, ' + @cols + ' 

          From
          (
            Select distinct S.First_NameUr  + S.Last_NameUr as FullName,c.ClassName,
            sub.SubNameUr,
            subr.obtainedMarks,sd.StudentDetailId--,(SUM(obtainedMarks)/COUNT(sd.StudentDetailId))as Percentage
            From TblStudentBioData s
            inner join TblStudentDetail sd on s.Student_ID = sd.Student_ID
            inner join TblStudentSubAss ssb on sd.StudentDetailID = ssb.StudentDetailID
            inner join TblClassSchedule csh on sd.ClassSchId = csh.ClassSchID
            inner join TblSubAss sba on ssb.SubAssId = sba.SubAssId 
            inner join TblClass c on csh.ClassID = c.ClassID
            inner join TblSubClassRel sc on sba.ClassSubRelId = sc.ClassSubRelId
            inner join TblSubject sub on sc.SubId = sub.SubId
            inner join TBLSubResult subr on ssb.StudentSubAssID = subr.StudentSubAssID
            where csh.ClassSchID =207
            group by S.First_NameUr,S.Last_NameUr,c.ClassName,sub.SubNameUr,subr.obtainedMarks,sd.studentdetailId
    ) tem   
    pivot
    (
        max(obtainedMarks)
        for SubNameUr in('+@cols+')

    )pivot1 '
```

above Query Gives me following Output

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want something like this:

```
SUM(obtainedMarks) OVER(PARTITION BY sd.StudentDetailId) / COUNT(sd.StudentDetailId) OVER(PARTITION BY sd.StudentDetailId) AS Percentage
```

Answer (score 0):

```
**how to add percentage column on every columns for pivot
DELETE TOP(100) PERCENT FROM PlusRS.rpt.RepairLevel
-- STEP NO. 2
INSERT INTO PlusRS.rpt.RepairLevel (ProgramID, PartNo, SerialNo, InvoiceFamily, RepairLevel)
SELECT  WOH.ProgramID
      , WOH.PartNo
      , WOH.SerialNo`enter code here`
      , PNA.Value AS InvoiceFamily
      , CASE WOH.RepairTypeID WHEN 42 THEN '1' 
                              WHEN 71 THEN '3'
                              ELSE MAX(PLVL.Value)
        END AS RepairLevel      
FROM pls.WOHeader WOH
INNER JOIN pls.WOStationHistory WSH ON WOH.ID = WSH.WOHeaderID
INNER JOIN pls.CodeRepairType CRT ON CRT.ID = WOH.RepairTypeID
INNER JOIN pls.WOLine WOL ON WOL.WOHeaderID = WOH.ID AND WOL.StatusID = 14
LEFT JOIN pls.PartNoAttribute PNA ON PNA.AttributeID = 354 AND PNA.ProgramID = WOH.ProgramID AND PNA.PartNo = WOH.PartNo 
LEFT JOIN pls.PartNoAttribute PLVL ON PLVL.AttributeID = 149 AND PNA.ProgramID = WOH.ProgramID AND PLVL.PartNo = WOL.ComponentPartNo
WHERE WSH.IsPass = 1 AND WSH.WorkStationID = 2  AND WOH.StatusID != 3
AND woh.ProgramID = '10001' and CONVERT(Date, WSH.lastactivitydate) >= '2022.04.11 ' AND CONVERT(Date, WSH.lastactivitydate) <= '2022.06.15'
GROUP BY  WOH.ProgramID
         , WOH.PartNo
         , WOH.SerialNo
         , PNA.Value
         , WOH.RepairTypeId
UPDATE  PlusRS.rpt.RepairLevel SET BCRatio = CASE WHEN RepairLevel = '0' THEN 9 
                                                  WHEN RepairLevel = '1' THEN 0
                                                  WHEN RepairLevel = '2' THEN 53
                                                  WHEN RepairLevel = '2.5' THEN 0
                                                  WHEN RepairLevel = '3' THEN 38
                                                  WHEN RepairLevel = 'O' THEN 0 
                                              END
Declare @sqlquery nvarchar(max),
@column nvarchar(max);
SELECT @column = COALESCE(@column + ',', '') + QUOTENAME(InvoiceFamily)
FROM
(
SELECT Distinct InvoiceFamily
FROM PlusRS.rpt.RepairLevel
) AS PIVOT_COLUMNS
DECLARE @ColumnForSum AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @ColumnForSum =REPLACE(@column,',','+')
SELECT @ColumnForSum =REPLACE(@ColumnForSum,'[','ISNULL([')
SELECT @ColumnForSum =REPLACE(@ColumnForSum,']','],0)')
SET @sqlquery =
N'select * into #TempBag from
(
SELECT SerialNo as Qty
, InvoiceFamily
, RepairLevel
, BCRatio
FROM
PlusRS.rpt.RepairLevel
)as t
pivot(
count(qty)
for InvoiceFamily In('+@column+')
)As Pvt_table
ORDER BY RepairLevel
select t.*, SUM('+@ColumnForSum+') Total from #TempBag t
GROUP BY RepairLevel,BCRatio,'+@column+'
Drop Table #TempBag'
EXEC sp_executesql @sqlquery**
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).